# How to make a php file which returns JSON

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I'm using a plugin called full calendar and it requires a `php` page to make a data source but I dont know how to make this page and I'm a bit confused
here is the js script

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

and here is what ive done

```
<?php
function GetEvents(){
    $post_data = array('title' => 'Test', 'start' => '2015-01-01');
    $post_data = json_encode($post_data);   
    return $post_data;
}
?>
```

examples are highly appreciated
thank you

Comment: It just requires data in a certain format. How you deliver it / where it comes from is up to you. Where / how do you have your calendar events stored?

Comment: Returning data from the `GetEvents` function doesn't return the result to the browser/js plugin. Have you looked at example code from the plugin?

Comment: Capital letters and punctuation are highly appreciated thank you ... unless you feel we're not worth the trouble? :(

Comment: the examples are just the properties of the plugin and not the php file source, thats why i dont know, well how do i return the json result to the plug in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the demos\php folder of your download from [fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/download/). There you will find example PHP files. get-events.php would play the role of the myfeed.php in your example.

Your example should more look like this:

```
<?php
    $post_data = array();

    //add first event
    $post_data[] = array('title' => 'Test', 'start' => '2015-01-01');

    //add second event
    $post_data[] = ...

    echo json_encode($post_data);   
?>
```

Comment: yeah some examples are there thanks , im sure my php file is correct but its still not working though

Comment: For starters, you have defined a function GetEvents() Does it get executed in some way? Try removing the function wrapping and try again.

Comment: sorry i didnt mention i changed it :), thats what ive done it now looks like this
 <?php
$post_data = array('title' => 'Test','start' => '2015-01-01');
echo json_encode($post_data);
exit();
?>

Comment: You have to return an array of arrays.
$post_data = array(array('title' => 'Test', 'start' => '2015.01.01'));

Comment: Its working, im just returning an array, thanks dude

Answer (score 3):

1. Say you are sending JSON: `header("content-type: application/json");`
2. Create some JSON: `$json = json_encode($some_data);`
3. Output the JSON: `print $json;`
4. Don't output anything else: `exit();`

Then get the output from your script and [test it](http://jsonlint.com/).